# EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION - Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift2, xcode7-beta5, exc-bad-instruction

I am making an iOS application with Swift 2. I have set 10 buttons tags' from 1-10. I am creating a loop for which var i loops through all numbers 1-10. A button I created is set to that tag. I am trying to set that button's image to nil. Here is my code:

```
var button : UIButton
    for var i = 1; i <= 10; i++ {
        print(i)
        button = view.viewWithTag(i) as! UIButton
        button.setImage(nil, forState: .Normal)
    }
```

What am I doing wrong? I have set 10 buttons tags'

Comment: When are you running this code? Have all the buttons been added as subviews of `view`?

Comment: The buttons are in my Main.storyboard. They have the tags as listed. This is part of the viewDidLoad.

Comment: Please try setting a break point before the for loop, and then typing `po self.view.subviews` ? Then you can confirm that all the views are added and have tags.

Comment: Sorry divergio, I did not understand what you said. What do you mean by 'po'. Also, I get a break point 1.1 error while setting a breakpoint there.

Comment: "po" is the debugger command to print an object.  https://www.objc.io/issues/19-debugging/lldb-debugging/ I'm trying to see the value of `self.view.subviews` before entering the for loop.